# Programa para descobrir caracteres repetidos em strings e imprimir ao contrário

Tags: c, string

Preciso descobrir quantos e quais caracteres repetidos existem em uma string (após informá-la). E também imprimir essa string ao contrário. Estou com grandes dificuldades. Aqui está parte do código que fiz até agora, porém com vários erros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 100

main () {       
    char palavra[TAM], c;
    int i = 0, aux = 0, contador = 0;

    printf("Digite uma palavra: \n" );
    while ((c=getchar())!= '\n'){
        palavra[i]=c;
        i++;        
    }

    palavra[i] = '\0';

    i = 0;

    while (palavra[i]!= '\0'){                  
        if(palavra[i]==palavra[i]){
            contador++;
        }                              

        printf ("%c = %d \n", palavra[i], contador);  
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: É óbvio que:    if(palavra[i]==palavra[i]){ sempre será verdadeiro. Creio que não é esta comparação que deseja fazer.

Comment: Será que você não quer verificar se cada caractere ocorre em outras posições da srting?

Comment: Regex não resolveria o problema?

Comment: Quando diz quantos elementos repetidos é quantas letras se repetem? Ou a quantidade de vezes que cada uma se repete ? Dê alguns exemplos para que seja mais claro

Comment: Quantas vezes cada elemento se repete. Por exemplo, a palavra arara. A letra a se repete por três vezes e a letra r por duas.

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta para tentar deixar a descrição do problema mais clara. Me diga o que achou, se acertei ou não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que você quer é contar quantas letras se repetem e quantas vezes, podemos usar um array auxiliar como um contador de ocorrências para ajudar. Eis o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 100
#define MAX_CHARS 256

int main() {       
    char palavra[TAM];
    int repeticoes[MAX_CHARS];
    int i, tamanho = 0;

    printf("Digite uma palavra: \n" );
    while (tamanho < TAM - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        palavra[tamanho] = c;
        tamanho++;
    }
    palavra[tamanho] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        repeticoes[palavra[i]]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHARS; i++) {
        if (repeticoes[i] > 0) {
            printf("%c = %d\n", (char) i, repeticoes[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i = tamanho - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         printf("%c", palavra[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Esse array `repeticoes` é o contador de ocorrências. O tipo `char` ocupa um byte, e portanto permite 256 combinações diferentes. Logo, esse será o tamanho do array e haverá uma posição no array para cada possível valor de `char`, cada uma delas representando quantas vezes esse valor de `char` aparece na palavra.

No primeiro `for`, a instrução `repeticoes[palavra[i]]++;` funciona primeiro com o `palavra[i]` que vai mapear o caractere da palavra diretamente para uma das posições do array `repeticoes`, posição essa que terá o seu valor incrementado. Esse laço irá percorrer toda a palavra (ou frase) digitada e ao contar os caracteres, vai montar o contador de ocorrências.

O segundo `for` apenas percorre os valores do contador de ocorrências, mostrando-os na tela. As posições com zeros são caracteres que não existem na palavra, motivo pelo qual não são mostrados.

O último `for` percorre a string `palavra` de trás-para-frente e imprime os caracteres um por vez, mostrando então a string de trás-para-frente.

Note também que eu coloquei um `tamanho < TAM - 1 &&` no `while`. O motivo disso é evitar que seja possível digitar-se mais caracteres do que cabe no array `palavra`. Usar apenas `tamanho < TAM` não é suficiente porque é necessário ainda espaço para o `\0`, e portanto usa-se `tamanho < TAM - 1`. Isso está antes do `&&` porque o tamanho tem que ser verificado antes que algum caractere a mais seja lido.

Comment: Eu só não entendi "histograma" em "podemos usar um array auxiliar como um histograma para ajudar"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O array auxiliar serve para contar as frequências de cada letra.

Comment: Isso eu entendi, mas a palavra "histograma" que me é arcana

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Substitui "histograma" por "contador de ocorrências" para evitar problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma simples função capaz de gravar em um vetor de inteiros a distribuição da frequência de cada caractere de uma determinada string (*ver [histograma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histograma)*), por exemplo:

```
void strhist( const char * str, int hist[ 256 ] )
{
    memset( hist, 0, sizeof(int) * 256 );

    while( *str )
        hist[ *str++ ]++;
}
```

Para exibir uma string de maneira inversa, você pode usar uma função contendo um laço `for` capaz de iterar na *string* de trás para frente, imprimindo caractere por caractere, veja só:

```
void inverso( const char * str )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        printf("%c", str[i] );

    printf("\n");
}
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM   (256)


void strhist( const char * str, int hist[ STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM ] )
{
    memset( hist, 0, sizeof(int) * STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM );

    while( *str )
        hist[ *str++ ]++;
}


void exibir_histograma( int hist[STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM], int min )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM; i++ )
    {
        if( (isprint(i)) && (hist[i] >= min) )
        {
            printf("[%c]: %d ", i, hist[i] );

            for( j = 0; j < hist[i]; j++ )
                printf("*");

            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


void inverso( const char * str )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        printf("%c", str[i] );

    printf("\n");
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    /* String original */
    char string[] = "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.";

    /* Histogama */
    int h[ STR_HISTOGRAM_MAX_TAM ];

    /* Exibe string original */
    printf("%s\n", string );

    /* Calcula histograma da string  */
    strhist( string, h );

    /* Exibe histograma das amostras com 2 ou mais ocorrencias */
    exibir_histograma( h, 2 );

    /* Exibe string invertida */
    inverso( string );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.
[ ]: 7 *******
[a]: 3 ***
[e]: 8 ********
[i]: 3 ***
[n]: 2 **
[o]: 2 **
[s]: 2 **
[t]: 2 **
[u]: 3 ***
[z]: 2 **
.sezilef sahnogec zed uiv aterex itubaj oneuqep mU
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso acima ele estaria pegando a quantidade de vezes que esse caractere se repete, acho que não é isso que o French K quis dizer, e sim quantos elementos se repetem exemplo:
se usarmos a palavra "matematica" temos 3 elementos que se repetem o (m) o (a) e o (t)
no caso acima o contador iria retornar aproximadamente 17, porem deveria retornar 3, pelo o que eu entendi da pergunta.
vou botar um código de exemplo me baseando no codigo do Gabriel Gomes mas não testei ele.

```
int contador=0;
char encontrados[TAM];
for(int i=0;palavras[i]!='\0';i++){
    for(int j=0;palavras[j]!='\0';j++){
        for(int z=0;i<contador;z++){
            if(plavras[i]==palavras[j] && i!=j && palavras[i]==encontrados[z]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(palavras[i]==palavras[j] && i!=j){
            contador++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que possa ser feito assim... A cada elemento ele compara com cada um e, encontrando um igual, incrementa o contador.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 100

main () {       
    char palavra[TAM];
    int contador = 0;

    printf("Digite uma palavra: \n" );
    scanf("%s", &palavra)

    for( i =0, palavra[i] != '\0'; i++ ){
        for( j =0, palavra[j] != '\0'; j++ ){
           if(palavra[i] == palavra[j])
             contador++;
         }
     }              

      printf ("%s = %d \n", &palavra, &contador);  
}
```

Comment: Mas o printf ("%s = %d \n", &palavra, &contador) não vai escrever somente uma única vez, se colocado nessa forma?

Comment: Na verdade para escrever a palavra seria printf ("%s = %d \n", palavra,&contador)

Comment: Isso seria para ler uma palavra contar o número de repetidos. Em seguida mostrar a palavra normal e a quantidade de caracteres repetidos